# What does gauge pressure indicate in fluid flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, terminology, definition, flow

In flow measurement, suppose we find gauge pressure difference between any two sections. Does this pressure is total pressure difference, I mean potential, kinetic and pressure head difference or only potential and pressure head difference?
In other sense, does this pressure indicate static pressure only or also dynamic pressure?

Answer (score 0):

The gauge pressure difference is equal to the static pressure difference.

Comment: In addition, if this gauge pressure difference occurs in a single section of pipe (not blocked in by valves or other equipment), AND both gauges are accurate, there will be fluid flowing in the pipe.